# Is there a way to hint the compiler to compute the entire value for multiple fields?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

I have following C# code:

```cs
public struct Color
{
    public byte R;
    public byte G;
    public byte B;
    public byte A;
}

public static Color F() 
{
    var c = new Color();

    c.R = 0xAA;
    c.G = 0xBB;
    c.B = 0xCC;
    c.A = 0xDD;

    return c;
}
```

which generates:

```
Program.G()
    L0000: push rax
    L0001: xor eax, eax
    L0003: mov [rsp], rax
    L0007: mov byte ptr [rsp], 0xaa      ; Can I somehow combine these lines automatically?
    L000b: mov byte ptr [rsp+1], 0xbb    ; Can I somehow combine these lines automatically?
    L0010: mov byte ptr [rsp+2], 0xcc    ; Can I somehow combine these lines automatically?
    L0015: mov byte ptr [rsp+3], 0xdd    ; Can I somehow combine these lines automatically?
    L001a: mov eax, [rsp]
    L001d: add rsp, 8
    L0021: ret
```

**What I want to achieve is: Instead of using 4 `MOV` instruction just use 1 `MOV` with the whole value.** For more context let's look at `GCC (O2)` and `CLANG (O2)`.

Here is the `C` code:

```c
typedef struct {
        int8_t r;
        int8_t g;
        int8_t b;
        int8_t a;
} color;
   
color 
f() {
        color c;
        
        c.r = 0xAA;
        c.g = 0xBB;
        c.b = 0xCC;
        c.a = 0xDD;
        
        return c;
}
```

This outputs:

```
; same on both GCC and Clang.
f():
        mov     eax, -573785174
        ret
```

## Question

Can I somehow tell the compiler to compute the entire value and use only *1* `MOV` instruction *automatically* (In case you ask your self why automatically? Then go to the NOTES section).

#### Notes

- What I found is: you can create a "union" like this and assign the value. E.g.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Color 
{
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte R;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte G;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte B;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte A;
    
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint Val;
}

public static Color G() 
{
    var c = new Color();

    c.Val = 0xAABBCCDD;

    return c;
}
```

this will generate:

```
Program.G()
    L0000: push rax
    L0001: xor eax, eax
    L0003: mov [rsp], rax
    L0007: mov dword ptr [rsp], 0xaabbccdd     ; this is what I am looking for. 
    L000e: mov eax, [rsp]
    L0011: add rsp, 8
    L0015: ret
```

Sure, I could go with this way. BUT I have to basically "remember" (not really, you do it once) all constants and assign them manually. Can I somehow hint the compiler to do this for me?

Comment: You are guilty of the crime of premature optimization.  You have already wasted more of your time thinking about this then you will ever spend initializing `Color` instances.  C# programmers rarely have a good time when worrying about machine language.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah.. I don't know. IMO it is important a: to know your tools and b: approach to best results.

Comment: You are right.  But that's particularly troublesome in C# because you have the IL in the middle.

Comment: @TimRoberts: There are tools like https://sharplab.io/ that make it not too bad to see machine code for single functions.  Of course in real life you hope that things will inline and optimize more, but if compile-time store coalescing doesn't happen here, it's unlikely to happen after inlining.  This looks like a reasonable way to test what you're going to get in practice for realistic C# use cases.  The fact that the asm is pretty crap is actually a *good* reason to try to hand-hold the compiler **if** this code is part of some really hot code that profiling finds is taking a lot of time.

Comment: Note that GCC had the same missed optimization from GCC3 to GCC7 IIRC, so about 2 decades after the GCC2.95 to GCC3 regression of not doing store coalescing.  So it's a non-trivial optimization for compilers to get right, although should be easier for a compiler targeting only x86 where unaligned dword stores are allowed.  Still not surprised a JIT doesn't do it.

Comment: Oh, now that I look more carefully, C#'s code-gen is extra dumb.  It needs the whole struct in a single register, but it chooses to create a store-forwarding stall by storing to memory and then loading that.  Even GCC6 isn't that bad, although GCC6 does miss the optimization if you pass it a reference to an existing `color` object and ask it to store into memory: https://godbolt.org/z/Ejd31bTKT.  Other wasted work in the C# version includes storing a `0` before writing all 4 fields, and also reserving stack space instead of using the shadow space above the ret addr ([rsp+8]).  Typical JIT :/